# Reading EDF+ Files in C#

Tags: c#, european-data-format

How can I read EDF+ Files in C# ?
I cannot find any idea on the internet, only with java or other languages.
For C# I only find libaries who can read simple EDF only, but I need to read annotations as well.

Comment: A single google search returned this [Library](https://github.com/rdtek/LibEDF)

Comment: I couldnt find it in nuget and it is just for EDF not EDF+ sadly.